# Degrees of comparison of adjectives

Tags: росіянізм, прикметники

Sometimes people are heard saying `саме головне`, `самий кращий` etc. as superlative degree of adjectives.

It sounds a bit odd to my ear.

I've found out that some experts, like Borys Rohoza in the article [Lessons of the State Language](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/225.htm) (Khreshchatyk e-paper),  call such forms a calque from Russian (*самое главное, самый лучший*) and consider thereof erroneous.

> 5. Не слід за російською мовою для вираження найвищого ступеня використовувати слово самий: самий близький, самий небезпечний, самий
>      щирий. **По-українському**: *найближчий*, *найнебезпечніший*, *найщиріший*.
>      Природні фрази: найбільша (а не сама більша) заслуга, найвартісніші (а
>      не самі вартісні) речі, найважливіший (а не самий важливий) іспит.

But some sources, e.g. [Outline of business Ukrainian](http://www.adm.dp.gov.ua/__c2257e83007a028b.nsf/b19e47826f35603ec2256f29003c32ff/71210a42c4e6ebc9c22571ed004c7948) worked out by Dnipropetrovsk Regional Institute of State Administration, tolerate such forms marking them as just rusticated.

> Складена форма найвищого ступеня, утворена за допомогою слова самий
>   (самий розумний, самий досконалий), має в українській мові
>   просторічний характер, у російській мові форми із самий (самый умный,
>   самый совершенный) – відповідають літературній нормі.

**Kindly advise what forms of degrees of comparison of adjectives (comparative and especially superlative) are formally approved and correct.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Historical Grammar of Ukrainian Language by L.P.Pavlenko quotes the comparative adjectives formed using suffix `-je-` in pra-slavic language: compare Russian form `более`. This form has been dropped in Ukrainian. Instead `-ш` and `-іш` are used.

Suffix `-ш` is derived from old slavic `-ьш`, where the reduced `-ь` has disappeared (`старьший`, for example, has the normative form `старший`). `-іш` is derived from old slavic `-ѣиш` (compare Russian `добрейший` and `добріший`).

Superlative adjectives are formed using prefix `най-`, or using `найбільш` or `найменш` with plain adjectives: `найзручніший` or `найбільш зручний`.

The use of `самий` is indeed "rustic" or "sociolectic".